# `for f in *; do cp "$f" "$f"_copy; done` doesn't work because "foo.png_copy". How to fix it?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

On Linux, the command:

`for f in *; do cp "$f" "$f"_copy; done`

doesn't work as expected because the "_copy" string is appended after the file extension, becoming `foo.png_copy` instead of `foo_copy.png`. How do I fix it? Can I slice the string?

Answer (score 6):

```
for f in *; do
    prefix="${f%.*}"
    suffix="${f:${#prefix}}"
    cp "$f" "${prefix}_copy${suffix}"
done
```

This finds the filename's prefix by trimming a suffix matching ".*". Note that if the filename doesn't have an extension, this will be the entire filename; if it has more than one period, it'll only remove the last one (e.g. for a file named "this.that.etc.png", it'll be trimmed to "this.that.etc"). It then finds the suffix by slicing the filename based on the length of the prefix (`${#prefix}`); this works as expected whether or not anything was removed.

Warning: this will treat any filename with a period in it has having an extension. For example, "file_v1.0" would be copied to "file_v1_copy.0".

Note: if you wanted, you could skip defining $suffix, and just use `${f:${#prefix}}` inline in the copy command, but I think this is clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Use `basename`, passing it a second argument:

```
for f in *; do
    cp "$f" "$(basename "$f" .png)_copy.png"
done
```

According to [`basename(1)`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=basename&sektion=0):

> ## SYNOPSIS
>
> `basename` *string* [*suffix*]
>
> ## DESCRIPTION
>
> The `basename` utility deletes […] a *suffix*, if given.

Comment: That's nice, but is there a string slice or replace function if I need it for some reason?

Comment: @Dokkat: You can use [Bash's parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion). I'm not very familiar with it, though, which is why this response took so long!

Answer (score 2):

if filename have only a  period

```
rename ".png" "_copy.png"  *.png
```

more

```
man rename
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] soon.  Given the use of `*` rather than `*.png` in the question, it may be that there are other files than just PNG files, in which case, what you're proposing will only handle the PNG files, not all the files.  You should also be aware that there are a few different versions of the `rename` command around. You're implying the use of one (relatively feeble) version; there's another version that uses Perl and Perl regular expressions (so `rename 's/.png$/_copy.png/' *.png` would do the job that your command is doing).  Even so, +1 and welcome.

Comment: On current Ubuntu's this regexp-version is standard; you can reach the one merlin mentioned then as `rename.ul`: `rename.ul . _copy. *`.  This way all files with a `.` in them get this one replaced with `_copy.`.  Also I want to mention that the OP didn't want to rename sth but to copy sth which is out of the scope of `rename` (with or without the `.ul`).

Comment: You're right, but even so, this was a great answer and gave me another great option, thanks.